# Extension to edit multiple articles in a same pattern?

Tags: extensions, database, content, batch

I am trying to fix an old joomla site so it can be responsive. In the articles, every image comes with `style="width:1150px;height:650px"`, I need to replace all these occurrences  with `style="width:100%"` or simply remove the whole `style` attribute.

There are some alternative ways to do this, like using javascript or directly going into database and do a search and replace. But I'd like to know if there is any extension that could accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: avoid using inline styles is also a good practise

Answer (score 4):

Actually you said it - you need to change the content in the database.

For doing such thing from within Joomla, **[Regular Labs DB Replacer Pro](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/dbreplacer)** is the tool to use.

Supporting regex searches, will allow you to do this change easily and quickly.

*Always keep up a backup before working directly with the database, something that DB replacer does.

Comment: Good extension, thank you. Sadly though,  the free verson doesn't support REGEX...

Comment: @shenkwen  Not all good things can be for free I guess - especially those that involve a lot of dedicated personal work - like regular labs extensions ;)

Comment: @shenkwen Maybe the cost of the Regular Labs can become part of your charge for the work. Even if not, the cost is probably cheaper than your time to manually edit the db content. And it'll probably be helpful down the road when you have other needs it can fulfill. It's not free, but neither is _your_ time.